# Horizontal Recyclerview inside fragment

Tags: android, xml, android-recyclerview

Am trying to add a horizontal `recylerview` inside a fragment but it's not showing up. If I change the orientation of `layoutManager` to vertical it works. Even a `flexLayout` is also visible but something is not good with horizontal `recylerview`.

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @BindView(R.id.toolbar)
    Toolbar toolbar;
    @BindView(R.id.viewPager)
    ViewPager viewPager;
    @BindView(R.id.dots_indicator)
    DotsIndicator dotsIndicator;
    PagerAdapter adapter;
    int fragNo;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);
        initStatusBar();
        viewPager.getChildCount();
        viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(4);
        adapter = new PagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        dotsIndicator.setViewPager(viewPager);
        Common.initCache();
    }

    private class PagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {

            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    return new FragOne();
                case 1:
                    return new FragTwo();
                case 2:
                    return new FragThree();
                default:
                    return new FragOne();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 3;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            fragNo = position;
            return "page" + position;
        }
    }

    private void initStatusBar() {
        Window w = getWindow();
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT == Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            w.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
            SystemBarTintManager tintManager = new SystemBarTintManager(this);
            tintManager.setStatusBarTintEnabled(true);
            tintManager.setTintColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.ib_fr_white));
        } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT == Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP || Build.VERSION.SDK_INT == Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1) {
            w.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
            w.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);

        } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT == Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            View view = w.getDecorView();
            int flags = view.getSystemUiVisibility();
            flags |= View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_BAR;
            view.setSystemUiVisibility(flags);
            getWindow().setStatusBarColor(Color.WHITE);
        } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT == Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            w.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);
        } else {
            w.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);
        }
    }
}
```

**FragOne**

```
    public class FragOne extends Fragment {

    @BindView(R.id.skills)
    RecyclerView rvSKills;
    @BindView(R.id.addedSkills)
    RecyclerView rvAddedSKills;
    @BindView(R.id.add_row_button)
    TextView addSkill;
    @BindView(R.id.editSkill)
    EditText editSkill;
    SuggestedSkillAdapter adapterSs;
    AddedSkillsAdapter adapterAs;
    Context context;
    List<String> addedSkills = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> suggestedSkills = new ArrayList<>();
    LinearLayoutManager  layoutManagerConnection;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_frag_one, container, false);
        ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
        context = getContext();
        FlexboxLayoutManager layoutManager = new FlexboxLayoutManager(context);
        rvSKills.addItemDecoration(new SpacesItemDecorationNew(0));//For equal distribution of columns.
        rvSKills.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        rvSKills.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        rvSKills.setHasFixedSize(false);
        String featuresAll = Constants.skills;
        String[] featuresSeperated = featuresAll.split(",");
        suggestedSkills.clear();
        suggestedSkills.addAll(Arrays.asList(featuresSeperated));
        adapterSs = new SuggestedSkillAdapter(R.layout.skill_filled_layout, suggestedSkills, context);
        rvSKills.setAdapter(adapterSs);
        adapterSs.notifyDataSetChanged();
        layoutManagerConnection = new LinearLayoutManager(this.getActivity(),LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL,false);
        initAddedSkillsRv();
        handleClicks();
        initeditText();
        return view;
    }

    private void initeditText() {
        editSkill.requestFocus();
        editSkill.setOnTouchListener((v, event) -> {
            editSkill.setHint("");
            return false;
        });

        editSkill.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_SENTENCES);
        editSkill.setHint("Type a skill or select from above");
        editSkill.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{filter});
        editSkill.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
                editSkill.setSelection(charSequence.length());
                if (charSequence.length() > 3) {
                    addSkill.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.quantum_googgreen500));
                } else {
                    addSkill.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.instabug_grey_hint_dark));
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
            }
        });
    }

    private void handleClicks() {
        addSkill.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            if (editSkill.getText().length() > 3 && !addedSkills.contains(editSkill.getText().toString())) {
                addedSkills.add(0, editSkill.getText().toString());

            } else Toast.makeText(context, "Add Something", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        });
    }

    public void initAddedSkillsRv() {
        rvAddedSKills.setNestedScrollingEnabled(true);
        rvAddedSKills.setLayoutManager(layoutManagerConnection);
        adapterAs = new AddedSkillsAdapter(R.layout.skill_filled_layout, suggestedSkills, context);
        rvAddedSKills.setAdapter(adapterAs);
        adapterSs.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    InputFilter filter = new InputFilter() {
        @Override
        public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {
            boolean keepOriginal = true;
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(end - start);
            for (int i = start; i < end; i++) {
                char c = source.charAt(i);
                if (isCharAllowed(c)) // put your condition here
                    sb.append(c);
                else
                    keepOriginal = false;
            }
            if (keepOriginal)
                return null;
            else {
                if (source instanceof Spanned) {
                    SpannableString sp = new SpannableString(sb);
                    TextUtils.copySpansFrom((Spanned) source, start, sb.length(), null, sp, 0);
                    return sp;
                } else {
                    return sb;
                }
            }
        }

        private boolean isCharAllowed(char c) {
            return Character.isLetter(c) || Character.isSpaceChar(c);
        }
    };
}
```

Not adding adapter as am able to see data in logs from the adapter.

Comment: i guess the problem is due to adding two horizontal scroll elements over on another that is why your horizontal scroll not working fine

Comment: this can be solve if you make your viewPager non Swappable

Comment: @MuhammadMuzammilSharif Is it possible to make viewPager non swippable?

Comment: yes it is, i will add it to answer

Answer (score 0):

**Write this code**

```
rvAddedSKills .setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, true));
```

Comment: Please check `rvAddedSKills` recyclerview. Your answer has a different recyclerview. That is working fine.

Comment: @kvaruna debug your code i think some time you are passing empty list to the adapter . check it .

Comment: No thats not the case as i have added in my question i can see the data in adapter in logs.

Comment: then what is the main problem .

Comment: Please read the question again and if possible remove this answer as this is not the perfect answer.